# is it possible to get current page variable's value into the loaded file inside a div with load() function?

Tags: php, javascript, load

i want to load my search_result.php file inside a div of my main php page using load() function. i have written a function that to parse a json code

```
json_parsing(document.getElementById('start_val').value, <?php echo $jsoncode;?>);
```

now i want when i load the search_result.php file using the following code

```
$("#search_result_cont").load("search_result.php");
```

the function inside it takes the value from current webpage element #start_value and php variable $jsoncode.

is it possible to do so?

Comment: If you only want to know whether it works or not, why don't you try it? Your approach is good...

Comment: i have tried and i know that normally it is not worked, i want to know that is there something we can do to have the values in loaded file?

Comment: jQuery removes the `<script>` tags from the html that is inserted into your div, no JS is executed

Comment: oh so how can i do so. i have tried it with different ways but nothing worked. i have tried .html() function also to reload html into the #search_result_cont div but that display the html in full page and removes previous html(the complete page html) and display only the content which is inside the #search_result_cont.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get( 'search_result.php'.function(text){
     eval(text); // text is without the script tags
},'text');
```

or

```
$.get( 'search_result.php'.function(json_text){
     json_parsing(document.getElementById('start_val').value, json_text); 
     // json_text is just $jsoncode
},'text');
```

Also, why are you parsing the json yourself when you can use $.parseJSON(text) and $.getJSON(); Usually problems like this indicate that you are trying to do something in a way that is not good programming design.